Number of runs to get probability distribution within an error
Considering an experiment of N boolean variables, each variable has an unknown probability to be 0 or 1.
My question is, is there a way to calculate how many runs of my experiment I need so that the sample distribution is within a given error ?
By error I mean how much the sample distribution reflects the "real" probability distribution of outcomes of my experiment.
[edit] to give some context, my experiment is a quantum computing experiment, a quantum algorithm outcomme is probabilistic, so we need to sample N times to have the result of the algorithm, so my boolean variables are qubits, and qubits can be entangled, so that some variables may depend to others, but sometimes it could not be the case, I can not know it in advance. But I'm interested to have both possible cases either my variables are iid or not.
I hope my question is clear and make sense.

Are your Boolean variables i.i.d.?

Thank you, I have edited the original question to give more context and thus the response of your question.

So to be clear you are trying to estimate $N$ separate probabilities? What metric are you using to measure the "error" of your sample distribution? Since it would need to be a metric in $\mathbb R^N$.
